# MT on Azure Service Bus. Why am I seeing System.InvalidOperationException: Can't create session when the connection is closing?

Tags: azureservicebus, masstransit

I am using MT 5.5.6 & Azure Service Bus

I am occasionally receiving the following exceptions thrown in all my services.

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Can't create session when the connection is closing.
at Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.Core.MessageReceiver.OnReceiveAsync(Int32 maxMessageCount, TimeSpan serverWaitTime)
```

Most of the time everything works as expected, but occasionally I am receiving the exception.
I am not using the sessions the feature of ASB.

I have a simple configuration for receiving large message data from a repository:

```
    x.AddBus(context => Bus.Factory.CreateUsingAzureServiceBus(sbc =>
    {
        var componentContext = context.Resolve<IComponentContext>();
        var host = sbc.Host(new Uri(_appSettings.GetSection("Azure")["ServiceBusUri"]), h =>
        {
            h.SharedAccessSignature(s =>
            {
                s.KeyName = _appSettings.GetSection("Azure")["ServiceBusKeyName"];
                s.SharedAccessKey = _appSettings.GetSection("Azure")["SharedAccessKey"];
                s.TokenTimeToLive = TimeSpan.FromDays(1);
                s.TokenScope = TokenScope.Namespace;
            });
        });

        sbc.ReceiveEndpoint(host, _appSettings.GetSection("Azure")["ReceiveQueue"], ep =>
        {
            ep.PrefetchCount = 16;
            ep.Consumer<BatchDocumentPresentedConsumer>(componentContext);
            ep.UseMessageData<BatchDocumentReceived>(componentContext.Resolve<IMessageDataRepository>());
        });

        sbc.UseSerilog();
    }));
});
```

This is the queue details from ASB (using Get-AzServiceBusQueue):

```
Name                                : filter
LockDuration                        : PT5M
AccessedAt                          : 11/05/2020 06:24:18
AutoDeleteOnIdle                    : P427D
CreatedAt                           : 12/03/2020 06:22:23
DefaultMessageTimeToLive            : P366D
DuplicateDetectionHistoryTimeWindow : PT10M
DeadLetteringOnMessageExpiration    : True
EnableExpress                       : False
EnablePartitioning                  : False
MaxDeliveryCount                    : 5
MaxSizeInMegabytes                  : 1024
MessageCount                        : 0
CountDetails                        : Microsoft.Azure.Management.ServiceBus.Models.MessageCountDetails
RequiresDuplicateDetection          : False
RequiresSession                     : False
SizeInBytes                         : 0
Status                              : Active
UpdatedAt                           : 12/03/2020 06:22:23
ForwardTo                           :
ForwardDeadLetteredMessagesTo       :
EnableBatchedOperations             : True
```

Why am I seeing this exception? Can it be because ASB is unavailable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe in that version of MassTransit, there were issues when a connection was interrupted between the application and Azure Service Bus, that it would recycle the connection, which would then restart all the consumers. However, the consumers didn't exit the loop correctly when the connection indicated it was stopping, so the receiver would try to restart, only to fail.

So, your final question, about ASB being unavailable, it's likely the connection was interrupted or the AMQP socket was disconnected due to any reason (transient failures happen) and that was thrown during the reconnection/restart of the consumer.